# os.path.isfile on an External file with full path names

Tags: python

New python coder.

Setting up a very basic script to remove various files in various locations,
essentially, an anti virus script. The script appears to run without issues:

```
import os
my_tup = (
'/Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder1/deleteme.txt',
'/Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder2/deleteme.txt',
'/Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder3/deleteme.txt')

for value in my_tup:
    if os.path.isfile(value):
        print (value, 'File exists\n')
    else:
        print (value, 'File Not Found\n')
```

I expect my list to get rather long, so I am now using an external file, that I can just add to. The external file will just be a tuple of path names. However, now the loop says none of the files exist, except or the very last entry from the loop?

```
import os
datafile = open("data.txt","r")
for value in datafile.readlines():
    if os.path.exists(value):
        print (value, 'File exists\n')
    else:
        print("Sorry, file does not exist: %s" % value)
datafile.close()
```

The output from this code is:

Sorry, file does not exist: /Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder1/deleteme.txt

Sorry, file does not exist: /Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder2/deleteme.txt

Sorry, file does not exist: /Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder3/deleteme.txt

/Users/kevin/Desktop/python/folder1/deleteme.txt   File exists

Hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: please fix your indentation for your second code block, right now you have a `for-else` statement which I hope isnt what you actually have running

Comment: If you have typed the code exactly as it appears here, the issue is indentation since the else clause is in the same indentation level as the for loop and not the same as the if conditional. In Python you can have an else clause after for. Check that.

Comment: As an aside, you can replace `for value in datafile.readlines():` with `for value in datafile:` because a file object will iterate the lines of the file.

Comment: @tdelaney: `s/can replace/should replace/`; `.readlines()` will eagerly slurp the whole file, and not begin iteration until the whole thing is read in, so it's both slower and requires more memory than iterating the file object directly.

Comment: Also, please use `with` statements. Explicit `.close()` is easy to forget or skip due to an exception; a block beginning `with open("data.txt","r") as datafile:` requires no `close`; it happens automatically when control flow leaves the `with` block.

Answer (score 4):

You've likely got newline characters (`\n`) at the end of each line.

Try calling `value.strip()` on each line to remove the newline character.

```
for value in datafile.readlines():
    value = value.strip()
    ... rest of code ...
```

Comment: You can't call `strip` in your for loop construct.

Comment: I think that changing `value = value.strip()` to `value = value.rstrip('\n')` works too! Am I right?

Comment: @Pardoido, not if the file happens to include any whitespace at the beginning of the line, like a `\t`.

Comment: Also `datafile.read().split('\n')` should work fine as long as you don't open the file in binary mode. In that case, `splitlines()` can solve that.

Comment: For speed and avoiding slurping the whole file at once, the best way to read stripped lines would be `for value in map(str.rstrip, datafile):` (or `str.strip` if leading should be removed too); if it's Python 2, make sure to `from future_builtins import map` so `map` doesn't eagerly slurp the whole file (using unbounded amounts of memory).

Comment: Sorry about the indenting, it was incorrect here only. 
I did in fact add the suggested line:  value = value.rstrip('\n')
and the loop now correctly identifies the files.

Many thanks to all...